# Get all rows using lambda expression Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am using below lambda expression to get users list:

```
var query = UserManager.Users
               .Include(u => u.Roles)
               .WhereIf(input.Role.HasValue, u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == input.Role.Value))
               .WhereIf(
                   !input.Filter.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                   u =>
                       u.Name.Contains(input.Filter) ||
                       u.Surname.Contains(input.Filter) ||
                       u.UserName.Contains(input.Filter) ||
                       u.EmailAddress.Contains(input.Filter)
               ).Select(store => new UserListDto { Id = store.Id, UserName = store.UserName + ' ' + store.Surname });

var userListDtos = query.MapTo<List<UserListDto>>();
```

It's returning the desired result. Means admin user and its sub users list.

But now I want all users list for super admin. I tried below but its giving only logged in user data (only 1 row).

```
var query = UserManager.Users.ToList();
```

Comment: Did you check if there are rows present in Users?

Comment: Yes, there are 7 records in users table

Comment: `UserManager.Users.ToList()` at least working fine on me, returning all users in context. Probably you have another part of code which messing up, check them also.

Comment: @AnandSystematix I think it should work. You haven't mentioned here about the input.filters. Are you going to drop that line while fetching all the records of superadmin role? Please check your input.filters if doing something there.

Comment: @AnandSystematix - Are you getting anything after the expression? I mean do you have any data in the database matching the criteria?

Comment: I am getting only 1 record of superadmin that is logged in, but I need all records as superadmin can access all users.